# How does tf.app.run() work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

How does `tf.app.run()` work in Tensorflow translate demo?

In `tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py`, there is a call to `tf.app.run()`. How is it being handled?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 154):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

means current file is executed under a shell instead of imported as a module.

```
tf.app.run()
```

As you can see through the file `app.py`

```
def run(main=None, argv=None):
  """Runs the program with an optional 'main' function and 'argv' list."""
  f = flags.FLAGS

  # Extract the args from the optional `argv` list.
  args = argv[1:] if argv else None

  # Parse the known flags from that list, or from the command
  # line otherwise.
  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  flags_passthrough = f._parse_flags(args=args)
  # pylint: enable=protected-access

  main = main or sys.modules['__main__'].main

  # Call the main function, passing through any arguments
  # to the final program.
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
```

Let's break line by line:

```
flags_passthrough = f._parse_flags(args=args)
```

This ensures that the argument you pass through command line is valid,e.g. 
`python my_model.py --data_dir='...' --max_iteration=10000` Actually, this feature is implemented based on python standard `argparse` module.

```
main = main or sys.modules['__main__'].main
```

The first `main` in right side of `=` is the first argument of current function `run(main=None, argv=None)`
. While `sys.modules['__main__']` means current running file(e.g. `my_model.py`).

So there are two cases:

1. You don't have a `main` function in `my_model.py` Then you have to
   call `tf.app.run(my_main_running_function)`
2. you have a `main` function in `my_model.py`. (This is mostly the case.)

Last line:

```
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
```

ensures your `main(argv)` or `my_main_running_function(argv)` function is called with parsed arguments properly.

Comment: A missing piece of the puzzle for beginner Tensorflow users: Tensorflow has some builtin command line flag handling mechanism. You can define your flags like `tf.flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 128, 'Number of images to process in a batch.')` and then if you use `tf.app.run()` it will set things up so that you can globally access the passed values of the flags you defined, like `tf.flags.FLAGS.batch_size` from wherever you need it in your code.

Comment: This is the better answer of the (current) three in my opinion. It explains the "How does tf.app.run() work", while the other two answers just say what it does.

Comment: Looks like the flags are handled by `abseil` which TF must have absorbed https://abseil.io/docs/python/guides/flags

Answer (score 77):

It's just a very quick wrapper that handles flag parsing and then dispatches to your own main. See the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py#L31-L48).

Comment: what does it mean "handles flag parsing"? Maybe you could add a link to inform beginners what that means?

Comment: It parses the command-line arguments supplied to the program using the flags package.  (which uses the standard 'argparse' library under the covers, with some wrappers).  It's linked from the code I linked to in my answer.

Comment: In app.py, what do 
`main = main or sys.modules['__main__'].main` and 
 `sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))` mean?

Comment: this seems weird to me, why wrap the main function in all that if you can just call it directly `main()`?

Comment: hAcKnRoCk:  if there's no main in the file, it instead uses whatever's in sys.modules['__main__'].main.  The sys.exit means to run the main command thus found using the args and any flags passed through, and to exit with the return value of main.  @CharlieParker - for compatibility with Google's existing python app libraries such as gflags and google-apputils.  See, for example, https://github.com/google/google-apputils

Comment: @dga how come this code gives out "ValueError: Iteration of zero-sized operands is not enabled" exception? Please refer to my post and feel free to answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773345/tf-app-run-error

Comment: @hAcKnRoCk,[is trying to call the main method with one argument.: More explanation can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51269497/6484358). That's the reason, we define main( _ ) vs main()

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing special in [`tf.app`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/app). This is just a [generic entry point script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py), which

> Runs the program with an optional 'main' function and 'argv' list.

It has nothing to do with neural networks and it just calls the main function, passing through any arguments to it.

Answer (score 7):

In simple terms, the job of **`tf.app.run()`** is to *first* set the global flags for later usage like:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import flags
f = flags.FLAGS
```

and then run your *custom main* function with a set of arguments.

For e.g. in [TensorFlow NMT](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt/tree/master/nmt) codebase, the very first entry point for the program execution for training/inference starts at this point (see below code)

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  nmt_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  add_arguments(nmt_parser)
  FLAGS, unparsed = nmt_parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

After parsing the arguments using `argparse`, with `tf.app.run()` you run the function "main" which is defined like:

```
def main(unused_argv):
  default_hparams = create_hparams(FLAGS)
  train_fn = train.train
  inference_fn = inference.inference
  run_main(FLAGS, default_hparams, train_fn, inference_fn)
```

So, after setting the flags for global use, **`tf.app.run()`** simply runs that `main` function that you pass to it with `argv` as its parameters.

P.S.: As [Salvador Dali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691911/2956066) says, it's just a good software engineering practice, I guess, although I'm not sure whether TensorFlow performs any optimized run of the `main` function than that was run using normal CPython.

Answer (score 3):

Google code depends on a lot on global flags being accessing in libraries/binaries/python scripts and so tf.app.run() parses out those flags to create a global state in FLAGs(or something similar) variable and then calls python main() as it should.

If they didn't have this call to tf.app.run(), then users might forget to do FLAGs parsing, leading to these libraries/binaries/scripts not having access to FLAGs they need.

Answer (score 1):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**: If you want to use `tf.app.run()` in **`Tensorflow 2.0`**, we should use the command,

`tf.compat.v1.app.run()` or you can use `tf_upgrade_v2` to convert `1.x` code to `2.0`.