# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main' for tf.app.run()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to test a short program, which is pretty simple, shown as follows

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf    
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS    
import tensorvision.train as train
import tensorvision.utils as utils    
flags.DEFINE_string('name', None,
                    'Append a name Tag to run.')

flags.DEFINE_string('hypes', 'hypes/medseg.json',
                    'File storing model parameters.')    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

However, running the program gives the following error message,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 43, in <module>
  tf.app.run()
File "/devl/tensorflow/tf_0.12/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 39, in run
main = main or sys.modules['__main__'].main
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

Comment: Shot in the dark- `from tensorflow import tensorflow as tf  `

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/40766480/5463534. You might need tp point it to an app.py with a main() function.

Comment: Is one of your files named `train.py`? That can cause issues when you `import tensorvision.train as train`.

Comment: Hi John, I read through the link you posted, but I am not clear how to "point tp to an app.py with a main()"?

Answer (score 14):

You either need a "def main(args)" function in your file:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf    
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS    
import tensorvision.train as train
import tensorvision.utils as utils    

def main(args):
    flags.DEFINE_string('name', None,
                        'Append a name Tag to run.')

    flags.DEFINE_string('hypes', 'hypes/medseg.json',
                        'File storing model parameters.')    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

or tf.app.run() can call an external function

```
tf.app.run(my_func)
```