# TensorFlow: module '__main__' has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on image recognition with Tensorflow following this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers. When I run the first chunk of codes, including "if **name** == "**main**":", I get an error.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-a542ecc63e7e> in <module>()
     12 
     13 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 14   tf.app.run()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py in run(main)
     27   f = flags.FLAGS
     28   flags_passthrough = f._parse_flags()
---> 29   main = main or sys.modules['__main__'].main
     30   sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'main'
```

What is the problem and how can I solve this?

I am using Python 3.6.2 under Anaconda environment on Jupiter Notebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main' for tf.app.run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004243/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-main-for-tf-app-run)

Comment: This (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43004243/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-main-for-tf-app-run) might help you out!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use main module checker like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

If you are on Jupiter notebook. This was probable an error in the documentation. Now you can [check](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) and this kind of checker is gone.

You would need to use that as an entry point if you create a python `.py` script.