# How to return variables from main()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Brand new to TensorFlow and am trying to modify some examples they give. For instance:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4806cb0646bd21f713722bd97c0d0262c575f7e0/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax_xla.py

```
"""Simple MNIST classifier example with JIT XLA and timelines.
"""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

FLAGS = None


def main(_):
  # Import data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
  y = tf.matmul(x, w) + b
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ....

  # Test trained model
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), y_)
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  print(sess.run(accuracy,
                 feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                            y_: mnist.test.labels}))
  sess.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--data_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
      help='Directory for storing input data')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--xla', type=bool, default=True, help='Turn xla via JIT on')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

This will print "0.9202" on the commandline. How do I return the value so that I can use it in other functions?

```
 val = tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
 print(val)
```

I get:

```
[pylint] E1111:Assigning to function call which doesn't return
```

Also, can't do anything after the function executes. If I try to print("this string") then the program exits before printing that.

EDIT:
Answers so far give the same error:

```
[pylint] E1111:Assigning to function call which doesn't return
```

I have looked through a lot of the examples for TF but cannot find an example of how to return the value rather than printing it to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here [How does tf.app.run() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703624/how-does-tf-app-run-work).

essentially tf.app.run is a wrapper which calls a main with some arguments. Either you change the print statment to assign the result to a variable and return it or within main you call  your own funtions to write some where

```
...
result = (sess.run(accuracy,
             feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                        y_: ...
sess.close()
return result
```

Maybe the full code of the tutorial makes this clearer:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py

Comment: I still get the same error since you aren't changing tf.app.run. [pylint] E1111:Assigning to function call which doesn't return

Answer (score 0):

You first gess was right, add `val =` to your function call. But you should also return a value from your function.

Replace:

```
print(sess.run(accuracy,
               feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                        y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

by:

```
return sess.run(accuracy,
             feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                        y_: mnist.test.labels})
```

Comment: I still get the same error since you aren't changing tf.app.run. [pylint] E1111:Assigning to function call which doesn't return