# Exception thrown when running tf.app.run()

Tags: python, tensorflow, flags

I am toying around with flags at the moment and came across some weird behavior when using `tf.app.run()`. The following code snippet should simply print the string given via the command line.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# command line flags
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('mystring', 'Hello World!',
                           '''String to print to console.''')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS


def main():

    print(FLAGS.mystring)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

During execution, this error is thrown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/path/flags.py', wdir='/path')
>
> File
>   "/home/abc/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 710, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/home/abc/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 101, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/path/flags.py", line 19, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>
> File
>   "/home/abc/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))
>
> TypeError: main() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

...which is strange because I do not give a single argument to main(). However, if I add an underscore `def main(_):`, it works without any errors.

I couldn't find a doc where this is use of the underscore is described. Does anybody know what happens here? Thank you!

Comment: Your main does not take any arguments.. but tensor flow app.run apparently is trying to pass an argument. "TypeError: main() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Comment: That's right, but I couldn't find the file that defines tf.app.run() to check its return values.

Comment: I suspect (Not a tensor flow expert) that this is so that tensor flow can forward command line arguments to your main.  When you put main(\_) you store the arguments in a variable named "\_" by convention that says you don't intend on using it but your function can now be called with an argument and avoids the error. "\_" is  a valid variable name :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message I see in Pycharm IDE when I execute your code is clearer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow/self.py", line 30, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "D:\\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", 
line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
TypeError: main() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

`_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))` is trying to call our *main* method with one argument.

This is the *run* method in [app.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9dc6c17797c065796603d9259b2aa57b3c07ff71/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py#L31-L48)

A stripped down version of the *run* method can be used to test.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import sys as _sys
from tensorflow.python.platform import flags


# command line flags
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('mystring', 'Hello World!',
                           '''String to print to console.''')

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

def run(main=None, argv=None):
  """Runs the program with an optional 'main' function and 'argv' list."""
  f = flags.FLAGS

  # Extract the args from the optional `argv` list.
  args = argv[1:] if argv else None

  # Parse the known flags from that list, or from the command
  # line otherwise.
  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  flags_passthrough = f._parse_flags(args=args)
  # pylint: enable=protected-access

  main = main or _sys.modules['__main__'].main

  print (_sys.argv[:1])

  # Call the main function, passing through any arguments
  # to the final program.
  #_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

  # Call the main function with no arguments
  #_sys.exit(main())


def main():
    print(FLAGS.mystring)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #tf.app.run()
    run()
```

`print(_sys.argv[1:])` prints `['D:/PycharmProjects/TensorFlow/self.py']` since
argv[0] is the script name passed to the interpreter.

Comment: +1 for finding the source. Unfortunately, I get an error when trying to execute your script: `AttributeError: _parse_flags`. No further information is given. Concerning the return value: as I understand it, run() calls the main function with a list as argument, which contains all arguments of argv AND all flags. Does the underscore operator in the main call mean that this exact list is received, but I don't care about it?

Comment: My tensorflow versions is 1.2.1. `_parse_flags` isn't there in your version. Yes. It is 'I don't care'

Comment: I am using v1.8. Anyway, as my question has been answered, I don't have to be able to run that code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can find the answer from this link for explaining how `app.py` runs[how app.py runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703624/how-does-tf-app-run-work)

You can also define your main function with `def main(argv=None): ...`, or like you do `def main(_): ...`, so this can make it works for you giving the main function parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when using cProfile and calling script with

```
python -m cProfile train.py
```

Seems like the problem was that tf.app.run called main inside cProfile which wasn't ready for argument passing. In my case the solution was to specify main in `tf.app.run()`:

```
tf.app.run(main=main)
```

Don't forget to add fake argument in main like this `def main(_):`.